# How to get "_pages" referenced at the site root in Jekyll?

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I have Jekyll site hosted on GitHub Pages. The file `_config.yml` has this content (excerpt):

```
# Defaults
defaults:
  # _pages
  - scope:
      path: "_pages"
      type: "pages"
    values:
      layout: "single"
      read_time: true
```

So when the site is built, I can open a page by its URL like this:
`https://repo.github.io/_pages/some-page/`

I read all the docs for Jekyll but it is not clear to me how to turn this URL to be `https://repo.github.io/some-page/` or maybe `https://repo.github.io/pages/some-page/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For eg. https://repo.github.io/some-page, you can put in `_pages` and config as such:

```
collections:
  pages:
    output: true
    permalink: /:name
```

Answer (score 5):

`_pages` can be seen as `collection` directory.
Therefore by simply having the following config:

```
collections:
  pages:
    output: true
```

will give you URLs like `https://repo.github.io/pages/some-page.html`

To get custom URLs you may add a `permalink` sub-config:

```
collections:
  pages:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:path/
```

will give you URLs like `https://repo.github.io/pages/some-page/`

For more possibilities, refer the [official docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#permalinks)